# VideoViewでCan't this play video

Tags: android, kotlin, videoview

VideoViewを用いてネット上にある動画の再生を試みています。
しかし、実行したところ"Can't this play video."と警告文が出て再生できません。
AndroidManifestにインターネット接続許可の文は付け加えています。

以下、VideoViewにUrlをセットし、再生を試みている部分のコードです。

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_live_streaming, container, false)
    val afterGameLivestreaming: VideoView = view.findViewById(R.id.after_game_live)
    afterGameLivestreaming.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaJHJK6Vzqg&t=1916s"))
    afterGameLivestreaming.start()

    return view
}
```

どうか、どなたかご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

指定しているURIが「動画ファイル」ではなく、YouTubeのサイト(Webページ)のURIであるからではないかと思います。
Web上でのフリー素材などの動画ファイルのURIを指定すれば、再生されるのではないでしょうか？

```
afterGameLivestreaming.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://hogehoge/fugafuga.mp4"))
```

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます。
まさしくおっしゃる通りで、Test用にEC2上に動画をアップロードしてそのURLを記載すれば再生することができました…